# Pandas merging two dataframes by removing only one row for every duplicate row between dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I am merging it. While merging it should remove duplicates. But for one duplicate row in frame 1 it should remove only one duplicate row in frame 2 even if there are two such rows like below
df1:

```
colA colB colC
  1    2    3
  1    1    2
  1    5    4
```

df2:

```
colA colB colC
 1    2    3
 1    2    3
 1    1    2
```

result:

```
colA colB colC
 1    2    3
 1    5    4
```

Here 1 set of 1 2 3 is removed from both dataframes (but another 1 2 3 dataset has been preserved). 1 1 2 set has been removed from both dataframes. 1 5 4 set has been preserved since no matching found in df2.

Is there any way to achieve this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'colA': [1, 1, 1],
                    'colB': [2, 1, 5],
                    'colC': [3, 2, 4]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'colA': [1, 1, 1],
                    'colB': [2, 2, 1],
                    'colC': [3, 3, 2]})

df1 = df1.groupby(['colA', 'colB', 'colC']).size().reset_index(name='count1')
df2 = df2.groupby(['colA', 'colB', 'colC']).size().reset_index(name='count2')

df_merged = pd.concat((df1, df2)).fillna(0)

df_final = df_merged.groupby(['colA', 'colB', 'colC'])\
    .apply(lambda x: x['count2'].sum() - x['count1'].sum())\
    .loc[lambda p: p != 0]\
    .reset_index()\
    .drop(0, axis=1)

print(df_final)
```

Output:

```
   colA  colB  colC
0     1     2     3
1     1     5     4
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer by following approach. David's answer is also working like a charm

```
result1 = result.groupby(['colA','colB','colC'], as_index=False).size()
result1 = result1[result1['size'] % 2 != 0]
```